# Inconsistent horizontal and vertical DIV spacing

Tags: css, border-spacing

I'm puzzled as to why on some browsers I get regular grid spacing between squares and others I get different spacing vertically than I do horizontally. I'm using Chrome Version 96.0.4664.93 (Official Build) (x86_64).

I was told a little hack which is `border-right: 4px solid white;` to the CSS style for `div>div`. However, I'd like to know why the inconsistency in rendering.

[grid_on_Chrome _96](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt5oD.png), [grid_on_Electron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Psufv.png)

```css
div>div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(68, 157, 230);
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="width: 50px; height: 
   50px;">
  </div>
  <div style="width: 50px; height: 
   50px;">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
  </div>
  <div style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would blame the single dot you have after the last div.

Comment: The spacing is still there after editing the dot. I pasted the code from the dev tools.

Comment: Your issue lies with using `display: inline-block`. There’s no need for that if you switch over to using flex box or grid.